# Simulation BPP by Pseudorandom Generator

Tags: complexity-theory

I use the following scribe to study  [Pseudorandom Generators](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/prgs.pdf).

The most intriguing question for me is how exactly PRG can be used in order to simulate BPP.

Let $A(x,r) \in BPP$, where $x$ is primary input and $r$ - randomness provided by BPP. Instead of $r$ we can provide $A$ with pseudorandom input $G(U_{d(n^c)})$ and according to the **Claim 7.6** from the scribe. $A$ with pseudorandom input differs from $A$ with random $r$ in less than half of running cases. The proof of Lemma shows that if it's so, that there is a distinguisher that distinguishes $U_{d(n^c)}$ from $U_{n^c}$ with advantage at least $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} > \frac{1}{8}$ which is contradicts to the definition of PRG.

Q: Where this advantage comes from? I simply don't understand what these numbers mean.

Q: Construction question. Why do need to run over all seeds of length $d(n^c)$ there are $2^{(d(n^c))}$ such string. For me it sounds like a strengthening of randomness because after that we use the majority as a result. But actually why do need that, why we cannot use single seed of length $d(n^c)$.

Q:Philosophical question. Why do we need PRG to be non-uniformly strong? Why we cannot use uniformly indistinguishable PRG? I saw the idea that the primary input $x$ to the $A$ can be used as advice, but I still don't understand why do we need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of a PRNG is coming up with a "deterministic" sequence that "looks like" random, in the sense that programs getting access to it act (roughly) as if they had access to a completely random string. The PRNG takes a seed or a key, and outputs a larger pseudorandom sequence. When simulating some probabilistic algorithm, instead of choosing a completely random string, it is enough to choose a random seed and use a PRNG.

How would you use a PRNG to simulate (say) a BPP algorithm? Suppose we had a PRNG that takes a seed of length $L = O(\log n)$, and $\epsilon$-fools every BPP algorithm. (Pseudorandom sequences don't look completely random, but in this case, using them instead of a random sequence changes the probability of any event by at most $\epsilon$.) That means that if we pick the seed at random, then the BPP algorithm returns the correct answer with probability at least $2/3-\epsilon$ (supposing that the original success probability was $2/3$ - that depends on your definition of BPP). If $\epsilon < 1/3$, then we have the following property:

- If we run the algorithm on a YES instance and a random seed, then it returns YES with probability larger than $1/2$.
- If we run the algorithm on a NO instance and a random seed, then it returns YES with probability less than $1/2$.

This property assumes we choose a random seed, but we wanted a deterministic algorithm. To that end, we go over *all possible seeds*, and calculate the probability that the algorithm returns YES. This is just the number of times that the algorithm returns YES divided by $2^L$. If the probability is larger than $1/2$ then it's a YES instance, otherwise its a NO instance. If indeed $L = O(\log n)$, then $2^L$ is polynomial, and we obtain a deterministic polynomial time algorithm.

Now regarding your questions:

1. I haven't looked at the scribal notes, but the advantage might come from the BPP algorithm.
2. Looking at a fixed seed is the same as looking at a fixed "random" sequence - you don't need a PRNG for that. All you know is that on average, the performance of the algorithm on a pseudorandom sequence correlates with whether the input is a YES or a NO instance. That doesn't say *anything* about a single seed.
3. As to uniformity, the program that your PRNG should fool is $A(x)$ for an arbitrary input $x$. While $A$ is a uniform circuit, $A(x)$ isn't, since $x$ could be arbitrary. Your PRNG should fool at one and the same time $A(x)$ for *all* possible inputs $x$.